# Converting tree-like object structure into an array and interating the whole thing

Tags: php, oop, loops, smarty

I have a tree-like object structure that consists of two types of objects:

1. object of class `Category`
2. object of class `CategoryLink`

The structure is the following:

The whole story begins with an array of `Categories` that have no `parent`
Each `Category` has a few unimportant properties and a few important:
`$parent` - containing an id of a parent `Category`,
`$children` - containin an array of childern `Categories` (may be empty if the category has no childern of course).
`$links` - containing an array of `CategoryLinks` (also possibly empty)

While `__constructing` a `Category`, I look for existing child `Categories` and `CategoryLinks`, and if there are some, I create their instances and add them to `$children` and `$links`, so this procedure repeats for the children and their children and so on, until a category with no children is reached.

So what this procedure does is that it basically creates a tree of `Categories` and their `Links`. This goes well enough, until I want to output this tree structure (using `Smarty`), and I'm not quite sure how to iterate over it the proper way. Desired output is something like this

```
Parent1 -its unimportant properties
    -Child1 - its unimportant properties
    -Child2 -...
        -Child2's Child1
        -Child2's Child2
    -Child3
Parent2
    -Child1
        -Child1's Child1
    -Child2
Parent3
...
```

I'm not sure if its better to iterate over it in PHP and convert it to a multi-dimensional array and iterate over it in Smarty, or do it all the way in Smarty.

*****note that I didn't mention objects of class `CategoryLink`, as the `Category` may contain only one-dimensional array of them, so iterating over them is rather easy, I'm just not sure how to iterate over the whole structure.

**What is the best | right way to do this?**

Comment: I dunno what Smarty is, but this seems like a classic depth-first-search?  It's trivial to implement recursively ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search )

Comment: +1 Why do the good questions never get Upvotes, whereas the stupid ones get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trees lend themselves to very elegant recursive operations.  In this case you're describing a depth-first pre-order traversal.  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_Traversal) might be useful.  As for the rest, pushing it into a multi-dimensional array sounds sensible enough if that's the easiest way for you to display it.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I'm not an SPL genius, but I think you could do something like this:

Implement [RecursiveIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.recursiveiterator.php). And then do:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $theMostTopParent
);
foreach ($iterator as $category) {
     // your code
}
```

As I said, I never worked with SPL, but I am really sure you can do something like this. So, why not give it a chance?

Nice thing about this: If Smarty has a foreach-loop this will work in smarty, too.